# Creating Map[String, Map[String, Object]] from List[Object]

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I'm just getting used to Scala and I have

```
case class Person(name: String, birthPlace: String, hairColor: String)
```

I know that there should be a good way to convert a List[Person] to

```
Map[Name, Map[Birthplace, Person]]
```

But, I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a general question: Why not store 2 separate maps (assuming multiple people can have the same birthplace)?  Map[Name,List[Person]] and Map[Birthplace,List[Person]] and then resultPersonListA.intersect(resultPersonListB) ? The advantage imo is that you have direct access to both maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be more then one person with the same name and birthplace, so a better data type for this kind of thing would be `Map[String, Map[String, Seq[Person]]`. 
You can create it using `.groupBy`:

```
    list
      .groupBy(_.name)
      .mapValues(_.groupBy(_.birthplace))
```

If you want to ignore multiple occurrences, you can discard them by adding this at the end:

```
      .mapValues(_.mapValues(_.head))
```